# MS Word format RevNum

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using the MS Word Quick Parts field RevNum, but I want to change the format for the number.

Right now the RevNum looks like "3", but I want to have it in a format such as "0.0.3". I change the format to 0.0.0, but it still only updates the field as 3.0.0. How can I achieve the goal that I am looking for?

I am using MS Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way, other than those already provided by Word.